# Set the expiration time of a process

Tags: processmaker

I would like to put an expiration time in my processes made in the processmaker v3.5.7 community,
I see that I can only set the time but even if it expires, they can be done to continue.
What I want to do is that when it expires they cannot be modified or sent to continue with that process.

Thanks in advance.

I hope to be able to send the process to several users, but when someone leaves time without reviewing or completing it, it may expire, it will be visible but not modifiable.

Answer (score 0):

Never done anything similar but it seems to me that you probably need to use a **Boundary Timer Event** in your task and make it so that if the timer expires, the process continues even if the user has not completed his task.

You can read about it [here](https://processmaker.gitbook.io/processmaker/designing-processes/process-design/process-modeling-element-descriptions#boundary-timer-event)

Comment: @kkd  Did you try using the battery timer event that I suggested?